# How do I parse datetime in KDB Q?

Tags: kdb

I have minutely data:

```
t                    o      h      l      c      v    
------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-04T09:00:00Z 105.45 105.45 103.6  103.6  17462
2016-01-04T09:03:00Z 103.7  103.99 103.7  103.99 893  
2016-01-04T09:06:00Z 103.7  103.7  103.7  103.7  335
```

Which I've read in with:

```
f: `:/home/chris/sync/us_equities/AAPL.csv
show flip `t`o`h`l`c`v!("SFFFFI";",")0: f
```

I'm trying to work out how to parse the ISO8601 timestamp into something KDB understands. How should I do it?

This is my first time using `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop the last character (`-1_`) from each value on the right (`/:`)  and then parse (`$`) to timestamp

```
f: `:/home/chris/sync/us_equities/AAPL.csv
tab:flip `t`o`h`l`c`v!("*FFFFI";",")0: f
update "P"$-1_/:t from tab
```

Note that `*` should be used for generic text data rather than `S`

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/tok/#unix-timestamps
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/drop/
- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/datatypes/#strings

Answer (score 1):

If you're using kdb v4.0 or greater you can parse it directly as type "P":

```
q)("PFFFFI";1#",")0:f
t                             o      h      l     c      v
--------------------------------------------------------------
2016.01.04D09:00:00.000000000 105.45 105.45 103.6 103.6  17462
2016.01.04D09:03:00.000000000 103.7  103.99 103.7 103.99 893
2016.01.04D09:06:00.000000000 103.7  103.7  103.7 103.7  335
```

For lower kdb versions you have to do as rianoc suggested.